# Form submit using jquery & passing values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to accomplish the following using jQuery:

```
frm_rooms.action="create_rooms.php?action=Save";
frm_rooms.submit();
```

I tried following jQuery but it doesn't work:

```
$('#frm_rooms').submit(function(event) <br/>{
    $.post("create_rooms.php", { action: "Save" } );
});
```

Comment: Hi all; thanks for suggestions & help :) .I got the solution from one of online guy thanks to him :)
 
$("#frm_rooms").attr("action", "create_rooms.php?action=Save") 
 $('#frm_rooms').submit();

Worked Fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
$('#frm_rooms').submit(function(event){
  $.post("create_rooms.php", {action: "Save" }, function(){ 
     alert("Data saved");
  });
  return false; //This is vital
});
```

If you want the parameters to be passed in the query string (GET method) use `$.get` instead of `$.post`.

**EDIT**: Thinking better, if you have fields inside your form that you want to be submitted, you should do:

```
$('#frm_rooms').submit(function(event){
  $.post("create_rooms.php?action=Save", $(this).serialize(), function(){ 
     alert("Data saved");
  });
  return false; //This is vital
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: As far as I remember, `return false` won't work on IE, it will still re-submit the form.

Comment: @Sayem No. It works cross browser. Return false is equivalent to `event.preventDefault()` plus `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Edgar thanks.. tried the script which you suggested. the form still doesnt get submitted. :(

Comment: @Sayem Thanks to you 
@arag Did you try using `$.get`? did you try the 2 ways I post? Does your form have elements to submit?

Comment: @ Edgar; thanks, yeah i have tried them. i didnt want ajax way. i just wanted form to be submitted normally with variable action value set to save ; just as this javascript " frm_rooms.action="create_rooms.php?action=Save";
" does; I got the solution; 1 of other guy suggested ; i have posted the thing just below my question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `preventDefault()` in your submit-function?

```
$('#frm_rooms').submit(function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("create_rooms.php", { action: "Save" } );
});
```

Also be aware that if you also have an input-element within your form, which name is 'submit'. The `submit`-method of jQuery won't work.

Comment: yeah had tried that event.preventDefault(); doesnt work. only $('#frm_rooms').submit() works fine. there is no input element with submit name/id

Answer (score 0):

Add `return false;` after `$.post()` to avoiding page reloading.

Comment: page doesn't reload . i want the page to get submitted as normal along with value of action attached

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('#frm_rooms').submit(function(event)
{
    $.post("create_rooms.php", {action: "Save" } );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you have an `input` element of type `submit` inside that form, then this method won't work. In that case, you will have to do something like following -

```
$('#mySubmitButton').click(function(event)                 // Suppose the id of that 
                                                           // submit button is mySubmitButton
{
    $.post("create_rooms.php", {action: "Save" } );
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If you want to provide success/failure message to the user, then modify the `$.post` method like this -

```
$.post("create_rooms.php", {action: "Save" }, function(data)
{
    // data contains server response. 
});
```

Comment: thanks...have tried it sayem.. its same thing happening. form not getting submitted

Answer (score 0):

You can add `.click()` method to your button:

```
$('#button').click(function() {
   //...
   $('#form').attr('action', 'action.php');
   return false;
})
```